# Error converting data type nvarchar to float in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a procedure from another procedure and so some calculation but I am getting an error.

Here is my first procedure:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE sp_myProc
      @REV1 FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
       @FREE_SAT = COUNT(CASE WHEN QTR_1 = 1 AND FREE_SAT = 1 AND ACTIVE_QUESTION = 1 AND ANSWER IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END)
   FROM table1  

   return @REV1
```

and the second procedure is like this:

```
 DECLARE REV1 FLOAT       
   exec sp_myProc[@REV1]
    select  S.ID, TYPE,
  CASE when TYPE = 'Option1' THEN COUNT(R.ANS)*100/@REV1 END AS Result

  FROM table2 S INNER JOIN
  table3 R ON S.ID = R.ID
  WHERE ANS= 'Yes'  
  GROUP BY ID, Type
```

Comment: Your procedure never touches @REV1.  Am I missing something.

Comment: What is the point of the procedure? It seems to take in a float value, run a select statement which has nothing to do with the parameter, then spits the parameter out again? Note that you've never assigned a value to this variable anywhere either.

Comment: In SQL Server, return can only return an int (and is usually reserved for error/status).

Comment: You should probably set @REV1 to an output parameter instead of doing the return. As others have said, this still won't work unless you actually set a value.

Comment: how would i do the output parameter

Comment: You specify OUTPUT after the param declaration
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004%28v=sql.105%29.aspx